# Artifactory decrypt passwords in debug mode

Tags: debugging, text, artifactory, password-encryption, logfile

Setup:
Artifactory 7.33.12 with pro license
(satellite pass-though multiple Artifactorys)
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

i switched all my artifactories to debug mode with logback.xml.
I changed all entries with level:info or with level:warn to level:debug

After these changes the artifactory server have began
right away to show passwords in plaintext: We have local and ldap user

Log snipped:

```
2022-04-04T10:46:57.758Z [jfrt ] [DEBUG] [bf2d7f554f68c503] [o.a.h.wire:87                 ] [ttp-nio-8080-exec-75] - http-outgoing-145231 >> "{"username":"username1","password":"plaintext"}"
2022-04-04T10:00:59.763Z [jfrt ] [DEBUG] [e227b7e38f035f2b] [o.a.h.wire:87                 ] [tp-nio-8080-exec-150] - http-outgoing-143844 >> "{"username":"username2","password":"plaintext"}"
```

The plaintext passwords was generated always if a user entered a wrong password (failed login)
this password was then in the artifactory logs in plaintext.
I switched immediately the logback.xml to level: warn and info and the passwords was encrypted again. Following log message looks weird:

```
./router-request.log:{"BackendAddr":"localhost:8040","ClientAddr":"127.0.0.1:38458","DownstreamContentSize":216532,"DownstreamStatus":200,"Duration":164389727,"RequestMethod":"GET","RequestPath":"/access/api/v1/users/?expand=passwords\u0026expand=encryptedData","StartUTC":"2022-04-08T09:52:53.86050316Z","level":"info","msg":"","request_Uber-Trace-Id":"28f3f17dc93f35c6:1b30ff214f5c8529:178287af7a330c6e:0","request_User-Agent":"JFrog Access Java Client/7.35.0 73500900  Artifactory/7.33.12 73312900","time":"2022-04-08T11:52:54+02:00"}
```

Did anyone know why this happened? Is that a bug?
I cant believe that was a intended behavior.
A production system can not display passwords in plaintext.

Anyone a Idea?
Please help

Comment: Hi... this is indeed a bug. We (I work at JFrog, the creator of Artifactory) are looking into it now.

Comment: We are working on changing this behavior, but since we were asked by customers to provide full requests data on DEBUG log levels, we cannot change it immediately. Please note, that using DEBUG log level is not recommended on production environment anyway, so it should be avoided. BTW - this issue is coming from the Apache HTTP client. Not from Artifactory code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202314/removing-httpclient-http-outgoing-log-lines